# Circular Generics with Jackson

Tags: java, generics, jackson

Using Jackson 2.1.2 (`com.fasterxml.jackson` packages), I am trying to define a common interface with a `@JsonValue` on it that may be of a different type than associated subclasses, but have been running into a problem when the interface's generics are circular, even if the circular generic is not used directly in the implementing class.

I have an interface that looks like this:

```java
public interface C<S, R extends C<S,R>> { 

}
```

(there are methods, but it turns out they are unimportant for our purposes here).

```java
public class TestSet<E> extends ForwardingSet<E> implements
        C<Set<E>, TestSet<E>> { 
    @JsonIgnore
    private final Set<E> delegate = Sets.newLinkedHashSet();

    @Override
    protected Set<E> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public Set<E> view() {
        return delegate;
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run the following test case:

```java
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    TestSet<String> tst = new TestSet<String>();

    tst.add("one");

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(tst));
}
```

It generates a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`:

```java
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Native Method)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolveBindings(TypeBindings.java:269)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings._resolve(TypeBindings.java:203)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeBindings.findType(TypeBindings.java:121)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromVariable(TypeFactory.java:807)
    at ...
```

Investigation reveals that the view() method is never called in this scenario.

I have found two possible changes that keep this from happening and show the desired behavior.  The first is to not use a circular generic in the interface.  Merely removing it is sufficient to keep the problem from occurring.  The second is to use an explicitly typed writer created with `mapper.writerWithType(Set.class)` (using the `@JsonSerialize` annotation with `as` does not appear to do it).  The latter is not really a good workaround for my use case unless I can somehow figure out how to reflect it in the annotation.

Not quite in the same category, but so far I have only seen it when `R` is some form of `java.util.Collection`.  If I declare it as `class TestSet<E> implements CRDT<Integer, TestSet<E>>` there is no error.

The question I have is: Is there something fundamental I am missing or some known way of doing this with annotations?

Comment: You should probably post this to the users or devel mailing list, your use case is quite complex

Comment: *"I have only seen it when `R` is some form of `java.util.Collection`"* Maybe it's because `TestSet<E>` itself is generic? What happens when you remove the `<E>`?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Good call. That appears to be correct.  If I strip the <E> entirely (or just from the ForwardingSet, though experimentation reveals that it is problematic with a Set<E> as well) then it works.   Merely stripping it from the implementation doesn't seem to change anything.